# Storing encrypted password in database but decrypt it on the client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

For context, I am making a password manager where users can store different accounts of service and their passwords. The idea was to store multiple hashed/encrypted passwords in the database and decrypt them on the client side to display them to the users without any input from the user.

What is the ideal way to go around this?

I am aware this method is not recommended as the encryption key could be stolen from the client side. Regardless, I would like to hear any thoughts on this.

Comment: as this doesn't have any code, information security SE may be a better place for this sort of question

Comment: @depperm okay, I will post a new question there. Thanks!